# Export custom types for third-party library in published NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm developing an npm package that uses a third-party library without types. I have types for it defined in a folder outside /src, as such:

```
/dist
/src
/types
  /third-party-library
    index.d.ts
```

index.d.ts looks something like this:

```
declare module 'third-party-library' {
  export interface INeedThis { ... }
}
```

And it's used in the code as such:

```
// src/index.ts for example
import { INeedThis } from 'third-party-library'
export interface SomeModel {
  config: INeedThis
}
```

When I use this package in another project, `SomeModel.config` shows up as `any`, which is confusing for the end user. This external type is not part of `/dist` so that makes sense, but where would I put it in `/dist`, or how should I go about packaging it properly? Or is this bad practise and I should go about it another way?